# How to stop specific external javascript file if the user's device is mobile device

Tags: javascript

I want to place an advertisement in my website,The ad is pop under ad. But sometimes on mobile devices it pop ups. I want to stop this ad code on mobiles and allow it on desktops. I have no knowledge of javascript. I tried this but it didn't worked. Because i think placing javascript inside javascript is not legal. What should i do to stop specific script on mobile devices? Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function isMobile() {
        return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    }

    if (!isMobile()) {
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Ad company URL Here"></script>
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just call a function whenever it is mobile? `if (isMobile()) {
       mobileFunction();
    }else{
       notMobileFunction();
       }`

Comment: @HéctorE Usually, the way ads are included on a page are simply by referencing their script from your page; you don't really get to control their inner workings, or make the ad appear yourself. That may or may not be the case here.

Comment: @Katana314 Didn't knew that. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You've got to `append` the new `script` element to the `document`

```
if (!isMobile()) {
   var src = "Ad company URL Here"; //Replace this with the, you know, actual source
   var scriptElem = document.createElement( 'script' );
   scriptElem.setAttribute('src', src);
   document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
}
```

Comment: Now the pop unders are not even working on desktop [link](http://quoteoftheday.liftupideas.com) On line 40 under My ad comment i have implemented it